# How to remove the cross icon in textbox that comes by default in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, textbox, sapui5

I am using UI5 text box which already has an option to clear the text by having a cross 'X' button.

But, in internet explorer along with the UI5 cross button it adds one more default cross mark for clearing the text, as in the picture,

[image]

How to remove the internet explorer's cross mark?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue is clearly no longer reproducible in UI5 (Open [this demo](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.87.4/#/entity/sap.m.SearchField/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelectionSearch) in IE11). Besides that, [UI5 doesn't support IE11](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the input element with the [::ms-clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx) property

```
.inputfieldname::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

**OR**

```
.inputfieldname::-ms-clear {
  width : 0;
  height: 0;
}
```